# Pagedown (WMD-Editor) Java Sanitizer (or OWASP xml rules)

Tags: java, html, markdown, wmd, owasp

I'm using the reimplementation of the famous wmd-javascript editor PageDown on client side (which is also used on Stackoverflow).

Now, I'm searching an HTML sanitizer for my server (runs tomcat7) which should only filter the HTML-subset that the PageDown editor can create.

My first choice was the OWASP project but I didn't found a xml rule file for PageDown - the rule-file for tinymce was too restrictive because it didn't include e.g. an "img"-tag.

Building my own set of rules is not only quite painful, it gives me security concerns. For this reason I wanted to ask if there are Java-classes or OWASP-Rules or something else out there which also have been tested.

Help would be very appreciated!

Thx in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSoup`.  
Its allows you to whitelist the elements you want in the resulting `HTML`.

See [jsoup_cookbook_cleaning-html_whitelist-sanitizer](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML Purifier, html5lib, or another system built specifically for HTML sanitization.  (Since you asked about OWASP: The good ones will use the OWASP whitelist of allowed tags, attributes, and other syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

[OWASP's new HTML Sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/) doesn't require you to maintain rules in an XML configuration language.

It comes with [pre-packaged](http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/Sanitizers.html) policies which can be unioned together, and if you want to do a custom policy, you can do that in Java code.